# Espresso swipeUp() wait too long after performed

Tags: android, testing, swipe, android-espresso

I am currently testing my NavigationDrawer with the Espresso library.
The purpose of this test is just to open the drawer and click on every items.

All of this works well, except that once I'm on the middle of the drawer, I perform a `perform(swipeUp())` which works too, but after the swipe, it waits approximately 30 seconds before executing the rest of the test.

Here is the code of my test :

```
public void testNavigate() {
    String[] frags = new String[] {
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_vehicles),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_smartphones),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_tools),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_pool),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_users),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_reporting),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_taxes),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_support),
            authActivity.getString(R.string.title_fragment_settings)
    };
    for (String elem : frags) {
        openDrawer(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (elem.equals(frags[frags.length / 2]))
            onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(swipeUp());
        onView(withText(elem)).perform(click());
    }
}
```

This test passes, the only problem is that it takes too long.

I even tried to override the `swipeUp()` method, by changing the parameters :

```
    private static ViewAction swipeUp() {
    return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, GeneralLocation.CENTER_LEFT,
            GeneralLocation.TOP_LEFT, Press.FINGER);
}
```

FYI, I'm swiping because the last element of my drawer isn't visible, so I can't perform `onClick()` on it without swiping.
I swipe only for one element, maybe the method is made for more elements, that's why I tried with other locations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure why it's so slow, but how about using `scrollTo()` rather than swiping? i.e. `onView(withText(elem)).perform(scrollTo(), click());`

Comment: Yeah this is kind of weird, since the waiting time is not constant : On an emulator this is faster than on my physical device, which is a powerful smartphone.
Unfortunately I didn't succeed to make it work with scrollTo() either.

Comment: What happened when you tried scrollTo? Also did you register some idling resources that could be slowing it down?

Comment: It threw an exception saying that elem is not in my view hierarchy. I tried to add the withId() method but it was the same.
No everything is local to my app, just static resources.

Comment: Oh, do you have a ListView within the DrawerLayout? If so, you'd need to use onData to match the lazily loaded list item.

Comment: I thought about this, but it's a NavigationView (with MenuItems).

Comment: did you ever find a solution? i am having the same issue. i cannot use "scrollToPosition()" because im trying to test a scroll listener but when i use "scrollToPosition()" dx and dy are 0. i get actual dx/dy values with swipiing action, but it takes a long time to continue the test